# How to integrate Airpush banner with AdMob Mediation?

Tags: android, admob, ads, airpush

I'm currently using AdMob Mediation for an Android App to display banner ads.

I would like to add Airpush banners too. The problem is that I can't find any documentation on the Web on how to achieve that.

Do you have integrate Airpush successfully with AdMob Mediation? How? If it is impossible, what  is a possible workaround?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem possible. From [here](https://support.google.com/admob/faq/2994346?hl=en&ref_topic=2403413&rd=1#2994402).

> Which ad networks are available in AdMob Mediation?
>
> AdMob Mediation currently works with Adfonic, AdMob, BrightRoll, HUNT
>   Mobile Ads, iAd, InMobi, Jumptap, Millennial, and MobFox. Don't see
>   your favorite ad network? Support for more ad networks is coming soon!

I don't see Airpush in their list.

A possible workaround would be to have two ad view, one with admob and the other with airpush (or any other ad network) and then implement [AdListener](https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/intermediate#android-adlistener) and in `onFailedToReceiveAd` hide the admob banner and show the airpush one.

I don't know airpush's API so I don't know how you go back from Airpush to Admob but I would look for something similar.

Edit: Looking further, your best bet to go back from Airpush to Admob is probably to use an AdCallbackListener and its onAdError(String) method. See [here](http://www.airpush.com/docs/index.php?title=Android_In-App_SDK_6.0_Documentation#4._AdCallbackListener%3a):

Comment: Thanks for your response. I actually use Custom Event for AppLift banner (AppBrain). Do you think it is possible to use Custom Event with Airpush also?

Comment: I do not know, I haven't used custom event yet so if you already used a custom event for AppBrain then you should be more qualified than me to determine if it is possible. A Priori it should as it looks to be exactly what custom events are for.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to do this is to use [Adience AdBoost](http://www.adience.com), they allow mediation with Airpush and a bunch of other networks. Worth a try...

Comment: I finally end up using MoPub for mediation with AirPush.  But I don't use AirPush anymore, I have switch to other networks (AdBuddies, AppLovin, AppNext, ChartBoost).  My CustomEventAdListener are open source : https://bitbucket.org/esavard/mopub-sdk (Disclaimer : I don't have updated the mopub-sdk lately, code could be broken)